# LinkedList: Push using dummy nodes

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, push, nodes

So, I am implementing a LinkedList using dummy nodes to represent the front and the back of the list that remain empty (or _head and _tail) respectively.

I'm attempting to create a push function that inserts an element to the front of the linked list, yet for some reason I keep getting an error.

Here's the code

```
void push(const T& x)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            _head->_next = _tail;
        }

            // Creates a new node with the user input data.
            Node* current = new Node;
            current->_data = x;

            current->_next = _head->_next;
            _head->_next = current;

            count++;
    }
```

Count is a instance variable that is used to keep track of the size of the list, and is defaulted to 0. And _data is the data value assigned to the current node.

For some reason, the compiler is stating that head->_next points to null, thus it can't assign the value to current. But I figured this issue would be handled by adding the if statement in the beginning.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `count = 0` is not `count == 0`. Compile with more warnings on.

Comment: @druckermanly Fixed that issue, what a rookie mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @druckermanly do you have any suggestions for the fix?

Comment: Not without the rest of your code, no. There are many things I suspect to be wrong, but you need to submit a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please put complete code

Comment: @Granzo *the compiler is stating that head->_next points to null,* -- The compiler didn't tell you this, as all the compiler does is determine if your module has no syntax errors and creates an object file if this is the case.